# ERROR : Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean WHEN running spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-starter

Hi I have thise message when i run my Spring boot application.
My main class have @SpringBootApplication and look like :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SouscriptionServiceOptionnelApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return configureApplication(builder);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
  }
  private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(SouscriptionServiceOptionnelApplication.class);
  }
```

the POM.XML look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!---->
    <groupId>fr.toto</groupId>
    <artifactId>toto</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <!---->
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>souscription-service-optionnel</name>
    <description>Souscription aux services optionnels</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- ISIIs commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>fr.toto.isiis</groupId>
            <artifactId>toto-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version> 
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache commons text -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet 2.5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot starters -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

2020-01-31 14:51:59.785 ERROR 358776 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at fr.edf.souscriptionserviceoptionnel.SouscriptionServiceOptionnelApplication.main(SouscriptionServiceOptionnelApplication.java:27) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.j``ar:1.5.4.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    ... 7 common frames omitted

Comment: Can you update your post with pom.xml

Comment: Done, and yes i need all these dependecies :-)

Comment: are you using embedded tomcat  to run the application? if So I think you need to remove the tomcat exclusion from the springboot-starter-web

Comment: No am note using embedded tomcat thats why it's excluded

Comment: How are you running your application? Given that it is starting on a thread named `main` it doesn’t look like you’ve deployed it to a container. You’ll need to do so if you’ve excluded the embedded container.